# Fetching NSMutableArray in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Good morning all, I have an issue I cannot figure out, been at it for quite some time now.

I am populating an `NSMutableArray` with objects and than saving them to Core Data.

My xcdatamodeld attribute is set for transformable. My subclass of `NSManagedObject` is `@NSManaged var carsname: NSMutableArray?`

I have tried changing it to `NSMutableString`, `NSArray`, `NSString`, but get the same results.

The issue is that when I do my Fetch Request I am only getting one object back from the Array when I know I have multiple objects in it. This is a `NSLog` of the fetch. Notice that The count for `NSMutableArray` is 3. But my HeaderForSection is only returning one. The second and third objects have data not the name that was originally populated in the array. And below that is my Save to core data and my Fetch from core data. Any Help is greatly appreciated.

> **THE COUNT FOR NSMUTABLE ARRAY IS 3 2015-12-04 09:49:42.768 Car-Doc-Safe-Plus[2997:891460] The Results has this in it (
>       " (entity: CarName; id: 0xd000000000040000
>    ; data:
>   {\n    carsname = \"(\n    Jeep\n)\";\n    documents = nil;\n})",
>       " (entity: CarName; id: 0xd000000000080000
>    ; data:
>   )",
>       " (entity: CarName; id: 0xd0000000000c0000
>    ; data:
>   )"**

```
-(void)saveToCoreData  {

    NSError *error;
    AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =  appDel.managedObjectContext;
    _entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CarName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newObject =[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:_entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newObject setValue:sectionName forKey:@"carsname"];
    [context save:&error];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    sectionName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    AppDelegate *appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDel.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"CarName"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to Fetch: %@",error);
    } else if ( results.count > 0){
        CarName *car = results[0];
        sectionName = car.carsname.mutableCopy;
        NSLog(@"The Results has this in it %@",results);

    }
}
```

Comment: When posting, you will want to post properly formatted code. You'll get more eyeballs on your question if it's easier to read.

Comment: I think you may be overcomplicating things: your code uses a single `CarName` object (the one returned by `results[0]` and tries to store a mutable array as one of its attributes (possible, but not a good idea).  Why not have many `CarName` objects, each with a simple string attribute, `name`?

Comment: Perfectly agree with @pbasdf. Are you missing some Core Data concepts? Next time, please format your question in a good way. Thank you.

Comment: Great guys, thanks so much for your help , been away from this . So I guess what you are saying is that coreData will not store multiple objects in one attribute ? And i should use multiple attributes ? , But I wanted the user to determine the amount of CarNames they wanted to add, I guess I will have to limit the number than.

Comment: @JohnZ Don't use a single object with multiple attributes, nor a single object with a single array attribute.  Use multiple objects with a single attribute.

Comment: Core data will do what you want, but it isn't the best approach generally. You're always creating new instances when you save. So you don't know the one you get out is the latest, it could be any. You log the instances in the result, not the size of the array you're talking about, and it shows 1 item in the array...

Comment: Guys, thank you for all your help on this, I believe i know how to tackle this now. Back to the drawing board. Much thanks..